# Running a function in the background in python

Tags: python, process, fork

I want a particular function to run in background using a child process and I would also like to terminate the child process when needed.

I am storing the pid of the child process in a file. So, when user types something like "python script.py exit", I can accept the command line arguement and kill the child.

```
import os
import time
import notify2
f = open("output.txt","w")
def notify(message):
    notify2.init("Cricket Matches")
    n = notify2.Notification("Live Update",message)
    n.show()

def fun():
    while(True):
        notify("match")

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    fun()
else:
    #do other stuff
    f1.write(str(pid))
```

Are there better alternatives to achieve the same? I have found nohup and screen tough to implement from the script(not from the command line).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Comment: specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/14924210/52074